# How to get the * (asterisk) to show in <kbd> mode if used twice

Tags: support, markdown

I tried to improve on an edit that should show

```
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>
```

in the text.

However this comes out as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+. I ended up inserting backquotes around the `*`, resulting in 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`*`</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`*`</kbd>

As single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> shows fine, 
is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can backslash the Markdown characters:

```
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\*</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\*</kbd>
```

gives

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>.

Comment: I could have sworn I had tried that as the first thing myself without getting the desired result %-).  You actually only have to escape one of the two to get the same effect.